# Picture syncing on Multiple Macs, iPhones, and iPad together so each device can update them all

Tags: macos, iphone, sync, iphoto, ipad

One of the owners of my company has put me to task to sync his pictures between the following devices together.

(2) iPhones
(2) iMacs
(1) Macbook Air
(1) iPad

Here is what is happening:

1. He has a camera that can upload pictures into iPhoto in either (1) of his iMacs, or Macbook Air.
2. He has (2) different iPhones. And here are how they are paired up

   iPhone -> iMac Home
   iPhone -> Macbook Air
3. He has MobileMe syncing Calendar, Contacts, and Notes across all devices
4. Currently we are using MobileMe web galleries to sync all photos, by having ME create each album and upload them to the MobileMe web gallery.

Now, the problem is he wants to just take pictures, and once he does that it syncs with all his devices, he'll even dock the iPad. Is there a better way to sync photos between all devices?

Answer (score 1):

Will [Dropbox](http://getdropbox.com) work? It won't sync them to the mobile devices immediately but they'll be available. He'll have to do a manual sync to iTunes to push them down to the mobile devices to get them into the Photos app.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 5.0 and OS X 10.7 plus the latest iPhoto, you can do this using iCloud. iCloud is basically the next-gen MobileMe.

Comment: I've looked into this. Turns out you can't put your entire photo library in the cloud. With Photostream I believe you can only sync 1000 photos with all your computers and devices, and that's it. You would need to copy them all to the respective devices and organize them on each of those devices. I need a 1 shot sync all end all for up to 10,000 photos, and there really is easy way to do this.